# Laravel Route Model Binding Dynamic Error Message

Tags: php, laravel

Given `/routes/api.php` file like this

```
// Article
Route::get('article/{article}', 'ArticleController@retrieve');
// Category
Route::get('category/{category}', 'CategoryController@retrieve');
```

And two controller like this:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function retrieve(Article $article)
    {
        return $article;
    }
}
```

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function retrieve(Category $category)
    {
        return $category;
    }
}
```

And now on `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` like this:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException &&
            $request->wantsJson())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Resource not found'
            ], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

When I search non-existing resource, both endpoint will response like this:

```
{ "error": "Resource not found" }
```

**So, how to pass custom message so that handler can output that message as a response?**

For example, when article is not found it will return like this:

```
{ "error": "Article not found" }
```

And when category is not found it will return like this:

```
{ "error": "Category not found" }
```

*I'm sorry if the title is misleading, as far as I learned from [this](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial) article, it is called **"Route Model Binding"**

Comment: you can get the Model name from the `ModelNotFoundException` with the `getModel` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$request->route()->parameterNames();` or `request()->route()->parameterNames();` value returned in array, if route expects more than 1 parameters, then use your logic

e.g : result is `array['category']` then you can modify like this

```
$param = $request->route()->parameterNames()[0];//to get parameter

//modifying message
return response()->json([
  'error' => "{ucfirst($param)} not found"
], 404);
```